# How to send angular html form input to spring boot rest web controller

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

i'm trying to send a list of 1 or more genes to my backend, through angular frontend and a spring boot rest web controller

my html page:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Clustertool gene(s) input</h1>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #clusterForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gene">gene(s) </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gene" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClustertoolService} from "../../clustertool.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cluster-tool',
  templateUrl: './cluster-tool.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cluster-tool.component.css']
})
export class ClusterToolComponent implements OnInit {
  onSubmit() {
    this.clustertoolService.getCell()
  }
  constructor(private clustertoolService: ClustertoolService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clustertoolService.getCell()
  }
}
```

servicepage

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClustertoolService {
  private clusterUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.clusterUrl = 'localhost:8080/clustertool/singleGene';
  }
  getCell(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.clusterUrl);
  }
}
```

app-routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

web controller

```
package singleCell.controllers.WebController;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import singleCell.DatabaseAccess.DAO.DatabaseRetriever;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/clustertool")
public class ClusterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/singleGene", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ArrayList singleGeneResponse(@RequestParam String gene){
        return DatabaseRetriever.getSingleGene(gene);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/multipleGenes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList multipleGeneResponse(@RequestParam List<String> genes){
        System.out.println(genes);
        return DatabaseRetriever.getMultipleGenes(genes);
    }

}
```

i want backend result to be send to the frontend, so i can further use it there. going to make plots out of the data with js libraries.

Comment: at this moment, nothing happens when i press submit, so i think i'm not handling the form properly in my component. But i don't think that's the only issue, i think i have to specify things in my app routing? i'm a rookie in angular, so i have difficulty understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `ClustertoolService.getCell()` should accept a parameter for `gene`

```
getCell(gene: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.clusterUrl+'?gene='+gene);
}
```

Then, you should call this method on submit of form with input value.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.clustertoolService.getCell(this.geneModel); // geneModel is ngModel for your input.
}
```

**EDIT:** in your HTML, you need to define ngModel on gene input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="gene" [(ngModel)]="geneModel" required>
```